# Valor atual de um campo "auto increment" no PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Gostaria de saber, quais as formas de se obter a posição atual do valor **"auto increment"** de colunas de uma tabela no *PostgreSQL*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O tipo de campo "Auto Increment" do Postgres é chamado de `SERIAL` para campos `INT` e `BIGSERIAL` para campos `BIGINT`.

O comando para criar este tipo de coluna é:

```sql
ALTER TABLE tabela ADD coluna SERIAL NOT NULL;
```

Ao criar este tipo de coluna, o banco de dados cria internamente uma `SEQUENCE` e configura o valor padrão da coluna como o próximo valor dessa `SEQUENCE`.
(mais informações sobre sequences [neste link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html))

O nome da `SEQUENCE` criada para campos do tipo `SERIAL` segue o formato:

*tabela* + '_' + *coluna* + '_seq'

Para obter o valor atual da coluna, é necessário saber o nome da `SEQUENCE` correspondente, e então usar o comando `CURRVAL`:

```sql
SELECT CURRVAL('nome_da_sequence');
```

Sendo assim, o tipo `SERIAL` nada mais é do que um "atalho" para o seguinte comando:

```sql
-- Criar uma coluna
ALTER TABLE tabela ADD COLUMN coluna INT NOT NULL;
-- Cria uma sequence que depende da coluna (OWNED BY), 
-- ou seja, quando a coluna for excluída, a sequence também será
CREATE SEQUENCE tabela_coluna_seq OWNED BY tabela.coluna;
-- Configurar o próximo valor da sequence (NEXTVAL) como o valor padrão da coluna
ALTER TABLE tabela ALTER COLUMN coluna SET DEFAULT NEXVAL('tabela_coluna_seq');
```

Também é possível obter a `SEQUENCE` de campos do tipo `SERIAL` usando a função `pg_get_serial_sequence`. Ficaria assim:

```sql
SELECT CURRVAL(pg_get_serial_sequence('tabela', 'coluna'))
```

Answer (score 1):

No `PostgreSQL` um campo "auto increment é um campo com tipo de dado `serial` ou `bigserial`.

Um tipo `serial` nada mais é que um inteiro com uma `sequence` associada.

Para manipular `sequences` você tem as seguintes funções: `currval(regclass)`, `lastval()`, `nextval(regclass)`, `setval(regclass, bigint)` e `setval(regclass, bigint, boolean)`.

Para mais detalhes consulte a [documentação](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html).

Comment: anonimo, sua resposta está parcialmente correta. Falta um exemplo de cada, para ficar um boa resposta e ter um bom conteúdo no site. A ideia foi essa, colocar a pergunta pois não consta aqui no SOpt. Aguardo sua edição :)

Comment: Você quer dizer repetir o que consta da documentação do software indicada?

Comment: Não... mais detalhes, exemplos do uso, um teste, um db-fiddle, etc Algo bem explicado, exemplificado, mostrando o uso, assim ajudará muitos que entrarem aqui e verem o tópico. Automaticamente, terá mais votos!